# xcode debugger not showing changes to variables

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have an IOS app and when I am stopped in the debugger I do not see changes to variables. I click the > by self and see the variable and click the > next to it and see the value. My code sets it to a new value. In the debug window it does not change. In the code I print the variable before and after I change it, the prints work fine. I am in the debugger looking at the variable, it has the old value, I step over the print and the new value is in the console.

A lot of stuff on stackoverlow references not debug or optimizing code. I have not touched anything in the build section and, as far as I can tell, I am using debug with no optimizations. I went into the settings for the app and debug was no optimization and I ran the app with no changes. I later went back in and found 2 places that had optimization level, in both places I changed both lines to be no optimization, this changed nothing.

I built a new app and , I broke it at the first print, ran it, at the first print x had a value of 1 in the left window, it printed 1, I stepped over the next statement and the left window still showed a value of 1, it printed 2.
When it starts the console has no warnings/errors. just says (lldb).

One strange thing was that I have seen doc that says if you hover over a variable it will display. When it is broke I hover over variables, for over 10 seconds, and nothing happens.

Version 14.3.1 (14E300c) of xcode and Version 14.3.1 (994) of the simulator. iPhone 14 Pro, IOS 16.4 simulated.

The new app is the default with an added @State variable and a button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var x = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
          Button ("hi") {
            print (x)
            x = 2
            print (x)
          }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```